# mysql foreign data wrapper for postgres with parameter substitution

Tags: postgresql, mysql

I have created a mysql_fdw for my postgres and when i try to run the one with a subquerry that has parameter substitution it does create a table but on querying the foreign table it throws an error:
 CREATE FOREIGN TABLE overtime_2010 (
    id integer,
    employee_id integer,
    hours integer)
    SERVER mysql_svr
    OPTIONS (query 'SELECT id, employee_id, hours FROM hr.overtime WHERE year =     ?year;');

The sql creates the foreign table but executing a select query yields The following error: connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.

Also trying to create a local table also fails with the above error
Create table local as select * from overtime_2010;

Comment: Well, where's the `year` parameter coming from?

Comment: year is coming from a another table, i am creating a table as a selection